# How do I use reaLline() to find matches in a file using regex and print them out to the console

Tags: regex

I am trying to have the user input a class number and name to pull up a list of information on that class I have on a file. I have figured out how to match the information using .toRegex. I can't figure out how to use the users input to find the match they need and not all matching in the file. I am very new to Regnex.

````
  val pattern = """\d+\s+([A-Z]+).\s+(\d+)\s.+\s+\w.+""".toRegex()
  val fileName = "src/main/kotlin/Enrollment.txt"
  var lines = File(fileName).readLines()// reads every line on the file
    do{
        print("please enter class name")
        var className = readLine()!!
        print("please enter class number ")
        var classNum = readLine()!!

        for(i in 0..(lines.size-1) ){
            var matchResult = pattern.find(lines[i])
             if(matchResult != null) {
                 var (className,classNum) = matchResult.groupValues
                 println("className: $className, class number: $classNum ")
             }
        }
    }while (readLine()!! != "EXIT") ```


example line from file 

      Name  Num
 0669 HELP  134  AN        CV  THING ETC  4.0  4.0 Smith P      001 0173  MTWTh       9:30A 10:30A    23     15     8  4.0
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a variable in the pattern that you get from the user .readLine()
Use a loop to check each line with another loop checking if the patter is in that line. pattern.containMatchIn()

````
        val className = readLine()!!.toUpperCase()
        print("please enter class number ")
        val classNum = readLine()!!

        val pattern = """\s+\d+\s+$className.\s+$classNum""".toRegex()
 for(i in 0..(lines.size-1) ) {
            var matchResult = pattern.find(lines[i])
            if(matchResult != null ){
                if (pattern.containsMatchIn(lines[i])) {
                    println(lines[i])
                  }
              }
     }```
````

Answer (score 1):

See [`MatchResult#groupValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/group-values.html) reference:

> This list has size of `groupCount + 1` where `groupCount` is the count
> of groups in the regular expression. Groups are indexed from 1 to
> `groupCount` and group with the index 0 corresponds to the entire
> match.
>
> If the group in the regular expression is optional and there were no
> match captured by that group, corresponding item in [groupValues](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/group-values.html)
> is an empty string.

You need

```
var (_, className,classNum) = matchResult.groupValues
```

See [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/KKSTJ24373):

```
val lines = "0669 HELP  134  AN        CV  THING ETC  4.0  4.0 Smith P      001 0173  MTWTh       9:30A 10:30A    23     15     8  4.0 "
val pattern = """^\d+\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(\d+)""".toRegex()
var matchResult = pattern.find(lines)
if(matchResult != null) {
    var (_, className,classNum) = matchResult.groupValues
    println("className: $className, class number: $classNum ")
}
// => className: HELP, class number: 134
```

I simplified the regex a bit since `find()` does not require a full string match to

```
^\d+\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p5KXuS/1/). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 1: one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits

Comment: How would you use the input from the user to pull up only the class name and number they want? I tried to use a variable in the regex pattern for the readline(). I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to work in the loop that reads the file. I end up with every line in the file instead of just the few lines that have the same class number and name. What does adding the third variable for the group do?

Comment: @Johnsonj39 If you have tried, where is it described in the question? What do you get? What do you expect to get?

Comment: " I can't figure out how to use the users input to find the match they need and not all matching in the file. I am very new to Regnex."

Comment: the code pulls up the information I need. The problem is I cant figure out how to use the input from the user example: class name "Math&" and class number "300"  with out it pulling up every class.

Comment: @Johnsonj39 Check [this Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/AVVQ37015).

Comment: I can't get it to work when I use it in a for loop for reading a file.

Comment: @Johnsonj39 Since I do not know how you are trying to get it to work, I cannot help you.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I didn't use patter.containsMatchIn(lines[i])) Plus using the variable in the pattern helps a lot. My loop was wrong making me think the variable in my patter was messing up my pattern.

Comment: @Johnsonj39 `.find()` should be enough. Please consider accepting the answer.